# Node watch on a docker-compose volume does not register delete events

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, watch, chokidar

I have a simple Node.js HTTP server running inside a docker container. One of the basic structural folders uses `volume` from `docker-compose.yml` to mirror the host and container directory.

Within the Node server, I have a watcher set up to track changes within the volumed directory, using the NPM package `chokidar` *(although I have tried multiple other watchers already with the same result)*.

```
const watcher = require("chokidar");

watcher
.watch("./app/experiments", { depth: 0, ignoreInitial: true })
.on("all", (event, path) => {
    console.log(event);
    // ... DO SOME EXPRESS AND WEBPACK STUFF 
});
```

When I run the Node server locally, the watcher correctly picks up changes to the watched directory. In this case, `chokidar` is reporting these as `addDir` or `unlinkDir`, which correspond to a scaffolding script I run to add or remove new folders into the directory *(which is served later via `express.static()`)*.

**STDOUT:**

```
> addDir
> EXPERIMENT ADDED!
> ...
> unlinkDir
> EXPERIMENT DELETED!
```

However, when I port  the application into a docker container, the behavior changes in a really strange way. I continue to get `addDir` events when I create new folders in the volumed directory, but I **no longer receive `unlinkDir` (delete) events!**. Note that this only happens if I add / delete a file within the volumed directory on the host machine. If I add / delete a file within that directory inside the docker container, my watcher correctly reports all of these events.

In *either case*, the volumed directory correctly mirrors itself. E.G. the files are *actually* deleted or added, and I can verify their existence on the host and by shelling into the docker container and running `ls`.

Any docker geniuses out there with sage wisdom on why this is happening?

**KEY STUFF:**

OS X 10.13.6

Docker Toolbox:

- Docker 18.03.0-ce
- docker-maching 0.14.0
- docker-compose 1.20.1
- virtualbox 5.2.18r124319

*Dockerfile:*

```
FROM node:8.12.0

WORKDIR /usr/dd-labs

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY app/ ./app
COPY server.js ./
COPY webpack/ ./webpack

EXPOSE 8080
```

*Docker-compose.yml:*

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    image: #someImageName
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: labs.docker
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/dd-labs/app
    command: [sh, -c, "npm run start:dev"]
```

Comment: Dinghy also has a known fs_event propagation limitation: https://github.com/codekitchen/dinghy/issues/264. Easiest solution is to use [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/docker-for-mac/install/%20%22Docker%20for%20Mac)

Comment: ^ this is the correct (and previously accepted) answer, why was it moved to a comment instead?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using Docker for Windows which has a [very well known lack of support](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/56) for file system events propagation from host to containers.

A work around is to use polling when in dev environment. With chokidar you'd want `usePolling: true` option.

Comment: I am actually running on OSX using Dinghy / docker toolbox. Should probably have included this haha

Comment: Edited OP to reflect current settings. Would prefer to diagnose than use the workaround but that might be the only way.

Comment: Can confirm `{ usePolling: true }` made it behave correctly and is a viable fallback.